# How to install private SVN repository using Bower?

Tags: javascript, svn, yeoman, bower

I am using the method given on official website for Subversion repository: [Bower Package Install](http://bower.io/#using-a-different-name-and-a-specific-version-of-a-package)

```
bower install svn+svn://svn.somename.com/project/Branches/MyBranch#32
```

I got:

```
bower ENOTFOUND Package svn+svn://svn.somename.com/project/Branches/MyBranch not found
```

Its a private package protected by login id and password. Does bower support `svn+svn://` packages?

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote and accept if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

What is `svn+svn://`?

I guess that you are mistyping [`svn+ssh://` or `svn://` scheme](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc.tbl-1). Make sure that the URL you enter is valid.

Comment: URL is svn://svn.somename.com/project/Branches/MyBranch#32 but bower guidlines says to put `svn+` before url if the package is from SVN repository.

Comment: @CaptainCode have you tried to enter just `svn://`?

Answer (score 0):

Per the schemes shown in the [bower docs](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install) I don't think bower supports the *svn:* scheme.

To install dependencies with bower ensure the subversion server is accessible via [http(s)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) or ssh.

Comment: And then use something like bower install svn+ **http**://svn.somename.com/project/Branches/MyBranch#32  (without the space after svn+)